# XMPP retrieve public rooms on openfire server + iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, xmpp, xmppframework, multiuserchat

I am developing a chat application in iphone using XMPPFramework. Everything is working great but stuck at the point. I want to retrieve a list of all public rooms but there is no method found in XMPPFramework. So can someone help me out to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to get list of all room

```
NSString* server = @"chat.shakespeare.lit"; //or whatever the server address for muc is
XMPPJID *servrJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:server];
XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"get" to:servJID];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:[xmppStream myJID].full];
NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query"];
[query addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"];
[iq addChild:query];
[xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```

If you have code to get the room of specific user please share it

Comment: i'm not getting rooms list only users are coming not groups

Comment: how i can active and delegate multiple chat room ?

Answer (score 1):

I use this code to query server directly, but I'm not sure that is the best way.

```
 XMPPIQ *iq = [[XMPPIQ alloc] initWithType:@"get"];
 NSString* conferenceHost = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"conference.%@", _xmppStream.hostName];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:conferenceHost];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:_host];
DDXMLElement *query = [DDXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"];
[iq addChild:query];
[_xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```

Hope this help someone.

By the way, if you adopt this solution, then you have to do some parse in delegate method:

```
 - (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq {
  }
```

I thing the best way is to parse method once the connection has started:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence {
    /* parse */
}
```

Then you check

```
  [[sender] from] domain]
```

if contains "conference." then you can think that sender is a room and finally you can add to NSMutableArray, for instance.
Also when a new room will be created, didReceivePresence will be called, so parser will add the new room.

So, you have:

```
NSMutableArray* rooms;
```

Your method will be:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getRooms {
    return _rooms;
}
```

Comment: how i can active and delegate multiple chat room ?